# Good practice way of child object calling parent object

Tags: c++

In object oriented design say I have a a box class and a dot class. Each box contains a list of dots and these dots have the ability to move. When these dots move outside the bounds of a box they are to be removed from that boxes list and instead be put into the neighboring boxes list of dots. This way we can always keep track of each dot in each box. The question is in regards to how to do a good callback from the dot. How do I from the dot class tell the box that is being left to remove this dot from its list?
A possible solution I have would be to include a parent reference in the dot class with a pointer to whichever box contains the dot but this seems like a code smell and I'd be curious how to avoid this and what the good practice solution would be.

If you think that it is a bad design to include the dots in a list in the box in the first place feel free to comment why and what your suggested solution is instead. 
Do keep in mind that I feel that this awkward callback in the call hierarchy is a reoccurring problem and even if in this case it is a bad idea to store the dots inside the box I'm still curious what the good practice way for a child to call a parent is.

Comment: Your problem is a good example of a problem that can be solved by an Observer pattern. Read more here, if later I can i will answer giving more details :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 1):

> Each box contains a list of dots [...]

I'm going to assume there is no inheritance relationship between your boxes and dots (the terms "child" and "parent" usually refer to that).

> A possible solution I have would be to include a parent reference in the dot class with a pointer to whichever box contains the dot but this seems like a code smell [...]

If you need the dots to *notify* their containing boxes, then you absolutely need a reference (pointer or otherwise) somewhere in your dot class. It can be hidden in a vector or with inheritance, but it still has to be there. The only other way I can think of is for the boxes to regularly check on all the dots they contain and update their lists that way. But that's probably not what you want.

> If you think that it is a bad design to include the dots in a list in the box in the first place [...]

Depending on what your boxes are exactly (I'm thinking about how they are placed in particular), there may very well be a better solution to your problem that doesn't involve any dependency between your boxes and dots. But without more details, I can't say much.

---

There are two main ways to code this notification mechanism. One is by making each dot store a direct pointer to its containing box and having a special "notify" method in the box class that the dot class knows about. When a dot needs to notify its containing box, it simply calls that method on the pointer it currently has. The other one is by giving each dot a callback function (can be a lambda or whatever) that implicitly contains a reference to the containing box. All the dot has to do to notify its containing box is to call this callback function. Presumably, this allows more flexibility on what the callback actually does, and hides the reference to the box in that callback. However, building this callback may seem more complicated if you aren't used to it.